# lebensgefährte vs lebenspartner

Tags: difference

Good day,

Lately I've been reading the einreise law due to corona situation. I've noticed a use of these two words (lebensgefährte und lebenspartner), but after googling a bit couldn't find a differnce between them - both are translated as life partner (both to English and my native language Russian). I guess they are very similar, with a slight emotional or legal difference.

Specifically it's being used in the Hessen corona einreise VO regulations:

> "Personen, die einreisen aufgrund des Besuchs von ... Lebensgefährtinnen, Lebensgefährten, Lebenspartnerinnen, Lebenspartnern oder ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebenspartner, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Lebenspartner), is the person you are married to or similarly **legally** connected with.

*Lebensgefährten*, *Lebensgefährtinnen* is just, who you currently happen to live with - no legal involvement.